# qt5-default installation error in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: package-management, source-packages

Error: Package 'qt5-default' has no installation candidate

I am trying to install ns3.27 on my ubuntu 20.04. meanwhile I am not able to install this package. I tried all the avaialable answers from the google, unfortuantely, nothing is working in my case.

Comment: Apologies as this is my first question and I am new to ubuntu as well. this is a part of my research.

Comment: Please add specific examples of what "available answers from the google" you have tried (include links), and what command you have used to install ns3 (with all the relevant output).  It looks to me as if the current Ubuntu package for 20.04 is 3.30, so first you probably should do `sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade` — it may just be that 3.27 depends on something no longer available, while 3.30 has changed the dependencies.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have tried installing dependencies:
1)
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
2)
sudo apt-get -y install qt5-default

3)
sudo apt -y install qt5-default
4)
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude -y install qt5-default